Gaussian process
Let $P$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ with cumulative distribution function $F$. Let $G_F \in D(\mathbb{R})$ denote the centered Gaussian process with covariance function $\text{cov}(G_F(s), G_F(t)) = F(\min(s, t)) - F(s)F(t)$, for all $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$. $D(\mathbb{R}$ is the set of cad process

Verify the existence of such a Gaussian process on $\mathbb{R}$.
Calculate $G_F$ (and specify the set of discontinuity of $G_F$) when $P$ is:
a) The Dirac measure at zero;
b) The Bernoulli distribution with parameter $p$, where $p \in (0, 1)$;
c) The discrete uniform distribution on $\{-1, 0, 1\}$;
d) The uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$.

I am not sure of my answers

Is the existence of such process due to the central limit theorem applied to the random variables $1(X_i \leq t)$ where $X_i$ are iid random variables with cdf $F$ ?

In the case of a Dirac measure is $G_F$ also a Dirac, with discontinuity points everywhere except in $0$ ?


In the other cases, is it a Gaussian process with the parameters given with the computation of the cdf F ? So I have to compute the cdf of the laws ?
Thanks.
